# How might I make advanced queries in SQLite to search for files by tags?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite, tagging

## What Am I Doing?

I'm writing a file tagging program in JavaScript using Electron and I'd like to use SQLite. I can't quite figure out how I'd implement searching by tags, though. I'm new to SQL and SQLite, so I'm not sure this is even possible solely through queries. How might I go about searching as described below?

## Searching Details:

I have looked into FTS3/4. I can do everything I want with that EXCEPT the wildcard searches, from the looks of it.

- **Search for files with all given tags:** `blue_sky AND green_grass`
- **Search for files without given tags:** `NOT blue_sky AND NOT green_grass`
- **Search for files with some of the given tags:** `green_sky OR blue_sky`
- **Search for files with wildcards *anywhere* in a tag:** `*sky AND *grass AND *bl*e*`
- **Combinations of the above:** `blue_sky AND green*` / `green_grass AND blue_sky OR green_sky`

## Tables:

May be changed

```
CREATE TABLE files (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE file_tags (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  file_id INTEGER,
  tag_id INTEGER
);
```

## Examples:

```
INSERT INTO files (name) VALUES ('file_1.png');
INSERT INTO files (name) VALUES ('file_2.png');
INSERT INTO files (name) VALUES ('file_3.png');
INSERT INTO files (name) VALUES ('file_4.png');

INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES ('blue_sky');
INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES ('green_sky');
INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES ('green_grass');
INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES ('blue_grass');
INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES ('greenish_blue_sky');


INSERT INTO file_tags (file_id, tag_id) VALUES(file1_id, blue_sky_id);
INSERT INTO file_tags (file_id, tag_id) VALUES(file1_id, green_grass_id);

INSERT INTO file_tags (file_id, tag_id) VALUES(file2_id, blue_sky_id);
INSERT INTO file_tags (file_id, tag_id) VALUES(file2_id, blue_grass_id);

INSERT INTO file_tags (file_id, tag_id) VALUES(file3_id, greenish_blue_sky_id);

INSERT INTO file_tags (file_id, tag_id) VALUES(file4_id, green_sky_id);
INSERT INTO file_tags (file_id, tag_id) VALUES(file4_id, blue_grass_id);
```

Query: `blue_sky and green_grass`
result: `file_1`

Query: `blue_sky or green_sky`
result: `file_1, file_2, file_4`

Query: `blue_sky and green_grass or blue_grass`
result: `file_1, file_2`

Query: `*ish*`
result: `file_3`

Query: `*bl*e*`
result: `file_1, file_2, file_3, file_4`

Query: `*sky and not blue_grass`
result: `file_1, file3`

Note: If SQLite isn't the right tool for the job, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Wildcard search can be achieved by using `LIKE`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm

Comment: I'm not sure about sqlLite because I don't use it.   Your database design looks fine.  It will enable you to meet your stated objectives.  What I see as an attention getter is your intent to use javascript.  It runs on clients.  Databases normally sit on servers.  Maybe Electron solves that problem.  I don't know what it is so I can't say.

Comment: @juzraai I have tried `LIKE` but I'm not sure how to structure a query using it that satisfies the rest of my conditions.

Comment: @DanBracuk Electron allows you to write desktop applications in HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I'm just writing a normal desktop app using a simple database to store the info I need. Edit: Link for anybody interested in Electron https://electron.atom.io/

Comment: Could you add a few lines of `insert ...` to your very useful lines of `create ...`? Please also give the desired result, based on that database content, for the given examples of desired searches.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've added a few examples.

Comment: By the way, try opening your database from SQLite command line tool and do a `.dump`, the result is practically a free MCVE. It is more convenient and the tricks like placeholder `file1_id` are not needed (which brake the syntax and make the MCVE not "paste-and-run").

Comment: Your MCVE seems to have earned you some upvotes. And an answer. :-)

Comment: Should `greenish_blue_sky_id` be `greenish_blue_grass_id` or would you like to add `greenish_blue_sky` to the tags and to the tags of file3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you could get this easier with a modified database structure.
E.g.

- using 'file_id' and 'tag_id' consistently,
  instead of sometimes 'id' in both cases
- using foreign keys (admittedly that might require an unavailable feature)

You might be able to use tag_ids as inpit in the first few cases, depending on where the keys come from (an "unexpecting user" would of course type colors). That would also reduce the risk of typos.

So what you could do is:

- use joins of the 'file_tags' table,
  one for each tag you want to use in your logic
- join the files table, to access file names for output
- use subqueries for using tag names instead of tag ids
  or use more joins instead, I demonstrated both below
- copy the search logic pretty directly into the 'where'
- group by file names, in order to get each file only once

Based on your nice MCVE, here are proposals for your example queries:

```
select fs.name from file_tags t1 
         inner join file_tags t2 on t1.file_id = t2.file_id
         inner join files fs on fs.id = t1.file_id
where t1.tag_id = (select id from tags where name = 'blue_sky')
  and t2.tag_id = (select id from tags where name = 'green_grass')
group by fs.name;

select fs.name from file_tags t1
         inner join file_tags t2 on t1.file_id = t2.file_id
         inner join files fs on fs.id = t1.file_id
where t1.tag_id = (select id from tags where name = 'blue_sky')
   or t2.tag_id = (select id from tags where name = 'green_sky')
group by fs.name;

-- note, here I had to derive from your desired output
-- that you want a '()' around the 'or'
select fs.name from file_tags t1
         inner join file_tags t2 on t1.file_id = t2.file_id
         inner join file_tags t3 on t1.file_id = t3.file_id
         inner join files fs on fs.id = t1.file_id
where t1.tag_id = (select id from tags where name = 'blue_sky')
 and (t2.tag_id = (select id from tags where name = 'green_grass')
   or t3.tag_id = (select id from tags where name = 'blue_grass')
     )
group by fs.name;

select fs.name from file_tags t1 
         inner join files fs on fs.id = t1.file_id
         inner join tags ts on ts.id = t1.tag_id
where ts.name like '%ish%'
group by fs.name;

select fs.name from file_tags t1 
         inner join files fs on fs.id = t1.file_id
         inner join tags ts on ts.id = t1.tag_id
where ts.name like '%bl%e%'
group by fs.name;

select fs.name from file_tags t1 
         inner join files fs on fs.id = t1.file_id
         inner join tags ts on ts.id = t1.tag_id
where ts.name like '%sky' and not ts.name = 'blue_grass'
group by fs.name;

select name from file_tags t1
         inner join files fs on t1.file_id = fs.id
where (select name from tags where id = t1.tag_id) like "%sky"
and not file_id in
        (select file_id from file_tags 
         where tag_id = (select id from tags where name = 'blue_grass')
        );
```

Output:

```
name
----------
file_1.png
name
----------
file_1.png
file_2.png
file_4.png
name
----------
file_1.png
file_2.png
name
----------
file_3.png
name
----------
file_1.png
file_2.png
file_3.png
file_4.png
name
----------
file_1.png
```

If I additionally add:

```
INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES ('greenish_blue_sky');
INSERT INTO file_tags (file_id, tag_id) VALUES(file3_id, greenish_blue_sky_id);
```

Then the last output part is:

```
name
----------
file_1.png
file_3.png
```

Using SQLite 3.18.0

Comment: My answer is slightly older (though posted more recently) than your edit which removes the file name extensions. It does not change the query code.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice answer. At a glance, it looks like exactly the thing I need. I'll have to spend some playing with these queries to understand them in detail. One thing, though. In the last example, I expect files 1 and 3, not 1, 2, and 4. It looks like your query should produce the output I expect. I don't understand why it doesn't.

Comment: I did not notice (can't say why). The reason is that both checks are done together on each of any tag, not on a combination. Joining the file_tags twice is needed to look at both. I will fix later (some 6h from now).

Comment: I "fixed" it. My query was wrong as I explained, however you only get file1 and file3 with an additional tag and with using it additionally on file3. Otherwise `greenish_blue_sky_id` is undefined. I had used `greenish_blue_grass_id` for making my MCVE.

Comment: The "not" is tough. You want a list of files which has no blue grass tag, instead of wrongly making a list with files which have at least one tag different than blue grass. Interesting.

Comment: `greenish_blue_sky_id` is undefined because I'm dumb and made a typo. It works perfectly, though! Thank you, this is incredibly useful. I don't think I could have figured this out on my own.